# Should questions about becoming a legal professional be on topic here

Tags: discussion, scope

It has been suggested that [What is the average cost of attending law school?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67544/what-is-the-average-cost-of-attending-law-school) be closed because it is "not about law". A user replied that  "Questions about getting into a legal career are on-topic" and another questioned the validity of this.

Another relevant question is [Does bar council of India not enroll candidates who passed 10+2 with vocational subjects?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/73318/does-bar-council-of-india-not-enroll-candidates-who-passed-102-with-vocational) which has also been closed as off-topic. I have votes to reopen it based on this thread.

Currently the law [help center](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mentions "Dealing with legal professionals" but not becoming a legal professional as on-topic. It seems to me that it **might** be reasonable to add questions about the career of a legal professional as on-topic. We have already had various questions about legal ethics which would fit under that general category.

Comment: @phomg  given the significant support for the answer by ohwilleke, and the lack of any stated opposition, what would it take to edit the help center to add "legal education and career" to the help center list of on-topic classes of questions? It seems I do not have the privilege of making such an edit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I favor making legal education and legal career questions on-topic, and amending the "help" page to reflect this decision.

There is no other forum likely to provide someone with the quality of advice of these topics elsewhere on Stack Exchange.

Also gaining insight into how lawyers are trained and what their career paths are like is useful for non-lawyers seeking to employer lawyers or to understand how and why they act the way they do, by providing insight into how they got where they did.

Comment: While I _generally_ agree about most such questions, I'm somewhat reluctant about questions whose answers are virtually guaranteed to quickly become outdated, such as the cost of attending law school.  While almost anything can change about the law, making an answer outdated, it's _far_ less likely in most cases.  To the extent that Stack Exchange exists to build a collection of accurate knowledge, such questions seem out of place, as their answers will remain highly ranked despite being outdated (and thus no longer accurate).